# Записать данные с json в строку String []

Tags: json, java

```
"musics" : [
    ".mp3",
    ".wav"
]
```

есть например такой json, с несколькими расширениями, но их прочитать и записать вот так

```
String [] music = new String [] {".mp3", ".wav"};
```

как только не пробовал, несовместимость типов, пробовал и преобразовать, на выходе null
При этом неизвестно количество форматов, они будут добавляться по нужде )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
    String jsonLine= "{\"musics\" : [\".mp3\",\".wav\"]}";
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("musics");

    for (JsonElement jsonElement : jarray) {
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsString());
    }
```